# Is there a shorter way for "Union All" using in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

We get data from 200 traffic station everyday and all stations have different table name like (KGM_000000000001_PVR). All stations have same column sorting with same column name. Always we get reports for different wish and we combine stations with union all as shown below example. For all time we combine them with union all and it is a bit hard. Is there a any other easy way to get this like report (using loop, case, for, etc.).

Levent

Thanks

Report code example:

---

```
SELECT count(class) from C2.KGM_000000000001_PVR WHERE class=9 and RECTIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.01.2012','DD.MM.YYYY') AND TO_DATE('01.01.2013','DD.MM.YYYY')
union all
SELECT count(class) from C2.KGM_000000000002_PVR WHERE class=9 and RECTIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.01.2012','DD.MM.YYYY') AND TO_DATE('01.01.2013','DD.MM.YYYY')
union all
SELECT count(class) from C2.KGM_000000000003_PVR WHERE class=9 and RECTIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.01.2012','DD.MM.YYYY') AND TO_DATE('01.01.2013','DD.MM.YYYY')
union all
.
.
.
SELECT count(class) from C2.KGM_000000000200_PVR WHERE class=9 and RECTIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.01.2012','DD.MM.YYYY') AND TO_DATE('01.01.2013','DD.MM.YYYY')
```

Comment: You could at one time generate a view over all tables and then just select using this view. At least shortens the SQL needed for each report.

Comment: Could you stored it all in a single table with a station name field?  That way you wouldn't need to union 200 different tables.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is an option

Comment: Why didn't you normalize that table and create only a single one?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Done like this, it can be like partitioning, without paying the option.

Comment: @Plouf!: but you spend the saved money working around the problems that stem from the (broken) design. I wonder what is cheaper...

Answer (score 3):

You may want to create a view on all these tables, with a pseudo columm "SOURCE" that shows the table name. Then your client code can just query this one view with any selection on the "SOURCE" column that you like.

```
CREATE VIEW KGM_ALL AS
SELECT 'KGM_000000000001_PVR' AS SOURCE, * FROM C2.KGM_000000000001_PVR
UNION ALL
SELECT 'KGM_000000000002_PVR' AS SOURCE, * FROM C2.KGM_000000000002_PVR
....

SELECT * from KGM_ALL where SOURCE in ('KGM_000000000001_PVR', ...)
```

As @Marlin stated, do not forget to create an Index on the source plus other other columns you usually select from.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for answers. If we create view by combining all tables, how will we take the each tables data differently from view. For example we want to get number of cars for one month from each table separately.(not total numbers of cars from all tables as one result). Can we do it by using view as you created? and what will be the necessary code?

Comment: @leventgulec: given the above view, you would add a `where source = 'KGM_000000000001_PVR'` to your SQL query. You can even query multiple sources at the same time.

Comment: @leventgulec, the comment from @Plouf! above is correct (even if the tone is questionable). You need something like "SELECT source, count(*) from KGM_ALL where month='Jan' GROUP BY SOURCE HAVING SOURCE IN ('..001', '..002')". This should get your the count for a given month for two areas. And Yes, @Plouf! is right, that is pretty basic SQL :-)

Comment: @mgaert, with your help we achieved to shorten the query. Thank you very much. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

An Index on the fields (class, RECTIME) on each table would reduce the time.  Be sure to include both fields in one index in the order specified.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use dynamic SQL:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm

You should then be able to iterate through your tables by concatenating their names (instead of using the numbers in the where clause) like this:

[how to write loop in pl/sql that goes over numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214847/how-to-write-loop-in-pl-sql-that-goes-over-numbers)